# И еще о пунктуации в прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении, где на конце стоит "а" для усиления сказанного (например: "Угомонись уже, а(?)") нужен ли вопросительный знак после "а"? Ведь предложения такого типа совсем не вопросительные — обычно там высказывается какая-то эмоциональная просьба.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопросительный знак ставится на конце вопросительных предложений. Ваше предложение вовсе не вопросительное, оно побудительное. Вопросительный знак не нужен. Ставится или точка, или восклицательный знак. Скорее, восклицательный знак, поскольку  Вы говорите об эмоциональности предложения, т.е. предложение по цели высказывания восклицательное.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе возможен и вопросительный знак. От интонации зависит, с которой фраза произнесена. Замените "а" на "ладно" или "хорошо" - произнесите, а потом с той же интонацией и исходный вариант. Ну и почему бы не поставить там вопросительный знак?